# How to cast Number or JSON to string when exporting data to excel using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, casting

I am using react-html-table-to-excel to convert my table to excel. There is a simple problem here. I can't convert Number to string in one column. post.did => Number I try to cast String like this
`<td>{String(post.did)}</td>` but when I opened .xls file in Excel
[this is what i see.](https://i.imgur.com/LmQowyj.png) How can solve this problem?

Comment: What is your "post.did" value before casting it to a string?

Comment: @RyanLe 902124000440

Comment: It looks like your excel cells doesn't have enough space, try to expand the comlumn.

Comment: @RyanLe I understand what you say, but I need this in string type.  I do not understand why excel accepts in integer this column when I casted a string.

Comment: Oh. I see your point now

Answer (score 0):

I think excel parses the value as a number try adding quotes around the number so excel will interpret the value as a string

```
<td>'{String(post.did)}'</td>
```